# ADS user details - subdomain - from vbs file

Tags: vbscript, adsi

I managed to get ADS users without specifying authentication details from my ADS domain(ex,mydomain.com). I used ADODB.Connection and ADODB.Command.

I also have sub-domains like test.mydomain.com. How to get user details from sub-domain, by specifying authentication details of a user belonging to test.mydomain.com .

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking how to query objects from the subdomain, or are you asking how to authenticate against the subdomain so you can query objects from it?

Comment: authenticate against subdomain, also am unable to query objects from subdomains, for main domain I'm able to get users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query records from trusted domains by using their LDAP name as the search base. However, since the DC of the parent domain doesn't contain the information about objects in the child domain it will generate a [referral](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx). The `ADODB.Command` object won't automatically [chase](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2009/07/06/referral-chasing.aspx) that referral, because the respective [named property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `"Chase referrals"` defaults to 0x00 ([`ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_NEVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). You have to set the property to one of the following two values

- `ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_SUBORDINATE` (0x20)
- `ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_ALWAYS` (0x60)

to make your query follow the referral. Example:

```
base   = "<LDAP://dc=test,dc=example,dc=org>"
filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=foo*))"
attr   = "name,description"
scope  = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope
cmd.Properties("Chase referrals") = &h60  ' <-- here

Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

I wrote a wrapper class ([ADQuery](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml)) to encapsulate the boilerplate code for Active Directory queries (because I got fed up with writing it over and over again). With that you could simplify the above to something like this:

```
Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.SearchBase = "dc=test,dc=example,dc=org"
qry.Filter     = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=foo*))"
qry.Attributes = Array("name", "description")

Set rs = qry.Execute
```

Either way you may still need to run the script on a DC, though.

Comment: Tried this way but failed to get user info

Comment: How? Did you get an error? Did you run it on a DC? What were your query parameters? Did you verify that the query actually should return something? "Doesn't work" is totally insufficient information for any kind of troubleshooting.